# Blazor in self hosted OWIN on .NET Framework

Tags: c#, owin, self-hosting, blazor

I have a service written in .NET Framework that hosts its own webserver using OWIN.
Having read about [Blazor](https://blazor.net/), I want to start experimenting with it and try to host a Blazor webapp in this service.

However, I haven't found any good instructions on how to do self-hosting with Blazor, especially not on OWIN and .Net Framework. The question, then, is quite basic:

How can I host a Blazor webapp in my existing OWIN service?

PS: I'm looking for native solutions, so I will not convert my solution to .NET Core, nor do I want to compile the Blazor webapp in another solution then copying the files to be hosted using i.e. `Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles` middleware.

Comment: Blazor is a client application framework (running inside the browser), so technically speaking, hosting it in your service is possible (you just need to host the files and let the browser download them and execute). It is still an experimental product, so post to its GitHub repo to see if you can get some assistance.